# Why does the creation of a map in scala not need and allow the new operator?

Tags: scala, new-operator

We create a new map in scala using:

```
val treasureMap = Map[Int, String]()
```

But why is it illegal to use the new operator here?

```
val treasureMap = new Map[Int, String]()
```

I thought new is for creating new object and in the example above I AM creating a new object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map` is a `trait` (like an interface in `java`) - it's a contract without implementation.

Without `new` you are using factory method `apply` of singleton object named [`Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Map%24):

```
val treasureMap = Map.apply[Int, String]()
```

In `scala` you could call an `apply` method of any object by placing brackets after object name:

```
val functionIncrement = (_: Int) + 1

functionIncrement(2)
// 3

functionIncrement.apply(2)
// 3

val treasureMap = Map.apply(1 -> "a")

treasureMap(1)
// a

treasureMap.apply(1)
// a
```